# Cobol. Perform MOVE Statement 12 times

Tags: cobol

I am creating a file expansion program and In my move statements i have a field that occurs 12 times. In order to do the Move 12 times I would like to use a perform or loop statement but i am not sure how to do these in cobol yet. Here is the line

```
 MOVE BUD-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(1) TO
                BUDNW-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(1)
```

How would I phrase this?

I know i can list the moves out manually but there are several of these that take place and i do not want to have to manually write out 80 plus moves.

Comment: You likely want a numeric variable instead of the `1` and use a `PERFORM VARYING var FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL var > 12`.

Comment: @SimonSobisch I would do that but this program calls for these moves to be subscripted.

Comment: Replace the digit `1` in your statement with the variable you define in your `PERFORM` statement. Taking Simon's statement this would become `MOVE BUD-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(var) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to hold the month number.

```
       03 MONTH-NO COMP PIC 9(4).
```

Then use the following:

```
       PERFORM VARYING MONTH-NO FROM 1 BY 1
       UNTIL MONTH-NO > 12
           MOVE BUD-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(MONTH-NO) TO
                BUDNW-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(MONTH-NO)
           MOVE BUD-CUR-BUDGET(MONTH-NO) TO 
                BUDNW-CUR-BUDGET(MONTH-NO)
           MOVE BUD-CUR-ACTUAL(MONTH-NO) TO 
                BUDNW-CUR-ACTUAL(MONTH-NO)
           MOVE BUD-PREV-YR-BUDGET(MONTH-NO) TO 
                BUDNW-PREV-YR-BUDGET(MONTH-NO)
           MOVE BUD-PREV-YR-ACTUAL(MONTH-NO) TO 
                BUDNW-PREV-YR-ACTUAL(MONTH-NO)
           MOVE BUD-2YRS-AGO-ACTUAL(MONTH-NO) TO 
                BUDNW-2YRS-AGO-ACTUAL(MONTH-NO)
       END-PERFORM
```

To replace all of this:

```
       MOVE BUD-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(1) TO
            BUDNW-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(1)
       MOVE BUD-CUR-BUDGET(1) TO 
            BUDNW-CUR-BUDGET(1)
       MOVE BUD-CUR-ACTUAL(1) TO 
            BUDNW-CUR-ACTUAL(1)
       MOVE BUD-PREV-YR-BUDGET(1) TO 
            BUDNW-PREV-YR-BUDGET(1)
       MOVE BUD-PREV-YR-ACTUAL(1) TO 
            BUDNW-PREV-YR-ACTUAL(1)
       MOVE BUD-2YRS-AGO-ACTUAL(1) TO 
            BUDNW-2YRS-AGO-ACTUAL(1)
       . . .
       MOVE BUD-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(12) TO
            BUDNW-NEXT-YR-BUDGET(12)
       MOVE BUD-CUR-BUDGET(12) TO 
            BUDNW-CUR-BUDGET(12)
       MOVE BUD-CUR-ACTUAL(12) TO 
            BUDNW-CUR-ACTUAL(12)
       MOVE BUD-PREV-YR-BUDGET(12) TO 
            BUDNW-PREV-YR-BUDGET(12)
       MOVE BUD-PREV-YR-ACTUAL(12) TO 
            BUDNW-PREV-YR-ACTUAL(12)
       MOVE BUD-2YRS-AGO-ACTUAL(12) TO 
            BUDNW-2YRS-AGO-ACTUAL(12)
```